# Angular.js 1.2 separating Controllers and Directives using an IIFE

Tags: angularjs, iife

I seem to come across an error when I try to define a controller within a directive that is wrapped in an IIFE. Although I could fixed this by adding ng-controller on the div in tableHelper.html. I was wondering the code below returns tableHelperCtrl as undefined.

Using angular.js 1.2.29

app.module.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [

    ]);
})();
```

tableHelper.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('tableHelperCtrl', tableHelperCtrl);

    function tableHelperCtrl() {

        var vm = this;
        vm.data = 'some data'
    }
})();
```

tableHelper.directive.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('tableHelper', tableHelper);

    function tableHelper() {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: './src/app/tableHelper/tableHelper.html',
            link: link,
            controller: tableHelperCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'vm'

        };
        return directive;
        }
    }
})();
```

tableHelper.html

```
<div>
    <p>Table Helpers Directive</p>
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <td>{{vm}}</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to `controller: tableHelperCtrl` to `controller: 'tableHelperCtrl'`

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign them the same controller. Give them a controller each and make them communicate through scope (using isolate scopes too if needed) or through a service.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your directive code. [Suresh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169230/angular-js-1-2-seperating-controllers-and-directives-using-an-iife#comment61873500_37169230) about wrapping the name of your controller in quotes seems to be one issue, although I've seen it work [without them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857735/using-controlleras-with-a-directive), I couldn't get it.

You've also got an extra closing curly brace, an you didn't define `link` although I guess we could assume that you've got it somewhere but left it out.

One more item is since you've defined your controller as 'vm', you want to use `vm.data` in your html instead of just `vm`.

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y19OKhUrbOlA1xLbt7w7?p=preview) that shows it working with these changes.